# what's the return of this function

Tags: arrays, function, return

Can someone please explain this code to me? How does JavaScript know which month it is if this code is not in a loop?

```javascript
  var month_name = function (dt) {
    mlist = [
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
    ];
    return mlist[dt.getMonth()];
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.getMonth()` returns the month of a Date object as a number between 0 and 11. This means the return statement accesses the index of the current month in the array and returns it. This works because JavaScript counts months starting at 0 not 1 like in "human" dates.